# Doctrine Annotations FileCacheReader.php Invalid argument

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an Entity that returns a record, I use this call in 20+ other places in the process. It returns the same record using the same query parms. If I run the class separately it works just fine but when combining it with the other calls I get this exception and the results are not returned.

```
Exception was thrown : 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
/myBundle/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/FileCacheReader.php line 242
```

Yes I cleared the Cache

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: 5.3.10 I think, what ever comes installed with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Seems that sometimes `FileCacheReader::getPropertyAnnotations()` returns an integer instead of an array. But only when debug is turned on. On the console, using `--no-debug` stopped the error for me.